# How can I use ImageMagick's path clipping with antialiased edges?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation, clipping, alpha-transparency

I have a JPG file which has a path defined. I'm able to successfully use `convert input.jpg -alpha transparent -clip -alpha opaque output.png` to make the area outside the path transparent and save it as a PNG file.

The problem is that the edges are not soft i.e. the edges of the clipped area are not anti-aliased at all - which `-clip` is probably not responsible for, I guess.

Is there a way to soften the edges or apply anti-aliasing when clipping the area along the path?

Comment: Would you care to give us an image?